# Accessing a variable outside a class

Tags: c++, oop, sdl, sdl-2

I have a variable in a `main.cpp` file like this:

```
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
```

and I have a class that is in separate files (a `.h` and a `.cpp` file). 
Inside the `.cpp` file I want to access `gRenderer` like this:

```
newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface );
```

I have tried putting an `SDL_Renderer` inside the class but when I compile it gives me only one warning that it is unused and when I run the program I get a message from SDL_GetError() :

> "Unable to create texture from colors.png! SDL Error: Invalid
>   renderer"

How can I do that inside the class that is in the separate files?

Comment: Is `gRenderer` NULL when you pass it into `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`?

Comment: You probably only want one renderer.

Comment: Pass the variable to the class constructor or to the relevant functions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access it, its file must be included in the file it will be used. Therefore, you should move the variable declaration to a header file (like `main.h`) and include it in `main.ccp` and in the files it will be used.

To do so, though, in the header file you should declare it as *extern*, and in `main.cpp`, defined normally:

```
main.h
extern SDL_Renderer* gRenderer;

main.cpp
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
```

That way, the variable is defined and can be used across multiple files normally, retaining its value.

If you want more information:
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)